# Is there a way to strip identifying data from commerce tables?

Tags: 7

I am interested in stripping personal addresses out of the  commerce_customer_profile and commerce_customer_profile_revisions database tables to sanitize the database for development purposes.

The site is using Drupal 7 and Drupal Commerce 7.x-1.13.

Has anyone come up with a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about sanitizing Commerce.  When I sanitize the db, I simply delete all the info in SQL:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE commerce_customer_profile;
TRUNCATE TABLE commerce_customer_profile_revision;
TRUNCATE TABLE field_data_commerce_customer_address;
TRUNCATE TABLE field_revision_commerce_customer_address;
TRUNCATE TABLE field_data_commerce_customer_billing;
TRUNCATE TABLE field_revision_commerce_customer_billing;
```

**NOTE: This is just an example.  You need to check your database and make sure you get all the relevant tables.**

If you want to use dummy data instead of deleting the data outright, you can use a statement like this:

```
UPDATE users SET users.name = users.uid WHERE users.uid > 0;
```

If you don't have a tool like PhpMyAdmin for accessing your database easily, I would use [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com) on macOS or [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) on Windows/Linux.

Drush has a `sql-sanitize` command but I have encountered several issues with it over the years.  I don't want to risk accidentally exposing anything before handing off a db to another developer, so I check the db anyway; in that case, there's no real speed advantage to using Drush vs. running the SQL myself and since I'm checking it with my own eyes I can be confident the job got done.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question, Patrick.  I had hoped to replace the existing addresses with something anonymous like you suggest for the users table.  They are stored in binary blobs.  I worked out sql that does this and throws no errors, but when I run it, the profile I 'changed' is still the same as it was before when I view it in Drupal.  I can't see anything in the table structure that suggests a lock.

Comment: Also, `drush sql-sanitize` does nothing for Commerce tables.  There is a sandbox for a module called commerce_sanitize but it appears to have been abandoned before they got to profile addresses.

Comment: @JeeElmore Make sure you changed all the relevant tables, including any revision tables.

Comment: Good catch...  Also, I am looking forward to trying your red wine debugging tip.  *grin   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via custom module, implementing [hook_drush_sql_sync_sanitize](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/drush.api.php/function/hook_drush_sql_sync_sanitize/8.0.x)

You can see detailed instruction on [this site](https://www.codeenigma.com/support/blog/doing-more-drush-sql-sanitize)

At the end, just run

```
drush sql-sanitize
```

**IMPORTANT: Drush sql-sanitize will sanitise data in the current database – you do not want to play with this on a live or production server!**

```
<?php
/**
 * @file /sites/all/modules/custom/es_gdpr_custom/es_gdpr_custom.drush.inc
 * Extends drush santize functionality.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_drush_sql_sync_sanitize.
 */
function es_gdpr_custom_drush_sql_sync_sanitize($source) {
  // Truncate cache tables with personal data.
  $query = "TRUNCATE cache_field;";
  $query .= "TRUNCATE cache_form;";

  drush_sql_register_post_sync_op('sanitise_cache tables', dt('Truncate cache tables with personal data: cache_field, cache_form'), $query);


  // The query to sanitise field_data_commerce_customer_address table.
  $query = "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_administrative_area = 'State';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_locality = 'Some City';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_dependent_locality = 'Some City';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_postal_code = '00000';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_thoroughfare = 'Some address';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_premise = '00';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_sub_premise = '00';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_organisation_name = 'Some organization';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_name_line = 'First and Last Name';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_first_name = 'First name';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_last_name = 'Last name';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_data_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_data = NULL;";

  drush_sql_register_post_sync_op('sanitise_commerce_address', dt('Sanitise field_data_commerce_customer_address table.'), $query);

  // The query to sanitise field_revision_commerce_customer_address table.
  $query = "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_administrative_area = 'State';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_locality = 'Some City';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_dependent_locality = 'Some City';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_postal_code = '00000';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_thoroughfare = 'Some address';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_premise = '00';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_sub_premise = '00';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_organisation_name = 'Some organization';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_name_line = 'First and Last Name';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_first_name = 'First name';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_last_name = 'Last name';";
  $query .= "UPDATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address SET commerce_customer_address_data = NULL;";

  drush_sql_register_post_sync_op('sanitise_commerce_address_rev', dt('Sanitise field_revision_commerce_customer_address table.'), $query);

  // The query to sanitise commerce_order table.
  $query = "UPDATE commerce_order SET mail = 'mail@localhost.com';";
  $query .= "UPDATE commerce_order SET data = NULL;";
  drush_sql_register_post_sync_op('sanitise_commerce_order', dt('Sanitise commerce_order table.'), $query);

  // The query to sanitise commerce_order_revision table.
  $query = "UPDATE commerce_order_revision SET mail = 'mail@localhost.com';";
  $query .= "UPDATE commerce_order_revision SET data = NULL;";
  drush_sql_register_post_sync_op('sanitise_commerce_order_rev', dt('Sanitise commerce_order_revision table.'), $query);

  /*
   * Sanitize custom fields.
   */

  // Place your custom fields here.
}
```